# Apollo Server studio not picking up schema from apollo set up

Tags: javascript, graphql, next.js, apollo-server, prisma

My stack is:

Apollo Server,
graphql,
prisma,
nextjs

I have added a resolver.ts and schema.ts for my graphql config under /graphql

`resolver.ts`

```
export const resolvers = {
  Query: {
      books: () => books,
    },
  };


const books = [
    {
      title: 'The Awakening',
      author: 'Kate Chopin',
    },
    {
      title: 'City of Glass',
      author: 'Paul Auster',
    },
  ];
```

`schema.ts`

```
import { gql } from "apollo-server-micro";

export const typeDefs = gql`

  # This "Book" type defines the queryable fields for every book in our data source.
  type Book {
    title: String
    author: String
  }

  # The "Query" type is special: it lists all of the available queries that
  # clients can execute, along with the return type for each. In this
  # case, the "books" query returns an array of zero or more Books (defined above).
  type Query {
    books: [Book]
  }
```

`/pages/api/graphql.ts`

```
// Next.js API route support: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction
import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server-micro';
import { typeDefs } from '../../graphql/schema';
import { resolvers } from '../../graphql/resolver';

const apolloServer = new ApolloServer ({typeDefs, resolvers});
const startServer = apolloServer.start();

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
  res.setHeader(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
    'https://studio.apollographql.com'
  );
  res.setHeader(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
    'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
  );
  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    res.end();
    return false;
  }
  await startServer;
  await apolloServer.createHandler({
    path: "/api/graphql",
  })(req, res);
}

export const config = {

  api: {
    bodyParse: false
  }

}
```

When I navigate to my api endpoint /api/graphql it takes me to the apollo studio explorer but its not picking up the endpoint or the schema.  The errors in dev tools seem to be studio libraries specifically they dont seem very helpful:

```
StaleWhileRevalidate.js:112 Uncaught (in promise) no-response: no-response :: [{"url":"https://cdn.segment.com/analytics.js/v1/xPczztcxJ39mG3oX3wle6XlgpwJ62XAA/analytics.min.js"}]
    at O._handle (https://studio.apollographql.com/service-worker.js:2:71211)
    at async O._getResponse (https://studio.apollographql.com/service-worker.js:2:47966)
_handle @ StaleWhileRevalidate.js:112
useTelemetryInitializer.ts:174          GET https://cdn.segment.com/analytics.js/v1/xPczztcxJ39mG3oX3wle6XlgpwJ62XAA/analytics.min.js net::ERR_FAILED
```

I don't think its anything to do with prisma as all I have done is set up a postgresql db and defined some basic schema.  Dont see why studio is not picking my endpoint, it doesn't seem to be CORS related as im not getting cross origin errors.

Studio screenshot:

[image: Studio Screenshot]

Comment: I haven't been able to create a minimal reproduction of this issue on the Apollo side of things, it seems like there's something in the handler function that's causing the error (I was able to setup the apollo-micro-server with the resolvers/typedefs mentioned and it loads as expected). The only thing I did differently from your example is set the following options while instantiating the Apollo Server: ```csrfPrevention: true,
  cache: 'bounded',
  plugins: [
    ApolloServerPluginLandingPageLocalDefault({ embed: true }),
  ]```

Comment: Did you find a solution to htis? Currently strugging with the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

I'm sorry if is too late, but the one thing that fixed this for me was cleaning the storage of the website